# Hiding a button remotely

Tags: ios, objective-c, button, httpwebrequest

I am trying to make it so that I can hide and unhide a button while my app is in the store (without me constantly updating the app and waiting for it to be reviewed).

The idea I had was to download a value from my website html, let's say it's n=1. Then my code in Xcode would say something like

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {

if (n==1) {
button.hidden = YES;
} 
if (n>1) {
button.hidden = NO;
}

}
```

This way, in theory, I could simply change the value of 'n' on my website and the button will be hidden or not based on the value. Is this the best way to do it? I am using Objective-C and am fairly new to it. If so, what code would I use to request a particular value from a website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a config file (JSON I find most convenient) remotely somewhere which your app can periodically download. Based on that configuration file you can lock/unlock functionalities in your app. So yes, you could store the variable in `NSUserDefaults` and in `viewDidLoad` you could have:

```
self.button.hidden = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]  integerForKey:@"your_key"] == 1
```

Beware though, if you are trying to "cheat" the reviewing process by doing this, I would advise against it.

Comment: I think he is talking mainly about the Server Side Connection

Comment: I'm not trying to cheat the process! I just want the button to be available/not available on certain days, it doesn't violate Apple's TOS but thank you for your hep!

Answer (score 1):

Well, theres a way to do that.

You can use [Parse](https://www.parse.com) to get app configurations from the cloud. Parse is really easy to use, they have a huge documentation to get you started (Really detailed and short guide).

Here is the [Quick Start Guide](https://www.parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/mobile/ios/native/existing).

After you set up your project and create an app on Parse. Head over to this section of the iOS Guide: [Link](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#config).

There you will see something they call 'Parse Config". That is storing values for certain variables of your app. (Images, Links, Value of certain variable, etc). Yo can change that anytime you want and it will be reflected on all the apps already installed, or in review.

Here is an example of code (AFTER YOU SET UP PARSE ON YOUR PROJECT AND CREATE A PARSE APP LINKED TO IT) on how to retrieve a value from the cloud.

```
 [PFConfig getConfigInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFConfig *config, NSError *error) {
   NSString *message = config[@"welcomeMessage"];
   NSLog(@"Yay! The message is %@", message);
 }];
```

[image: Parse App Panel]

Comment: I haven't used Parse before but I may explore using this option as well!

Comment: You'll love it @LodgeApps